# Login Required 401 Google Analytics API v3 C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, google-maps-api-3, google-analytics

Please Help me

I used V3 Google API for display Google Analytic data on UI, and All code is done but I got `json` like the following:

> "{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"required","message":"Login Required","locationType":"header","location":"Authorization"}],"code":401,"message":"Login Required"}}"

I used MVC4

thanks

Comment: where is authentication code ?

Comment: please refer https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v2/gdataAuthentication

Comment: I used this code : https://github.com/rmostafa/DotNetAnalyticsAPI   And I used Service account ,I am not getting any Error but when I debug and copy url and past on browser then I am getting above json, What I am missing , is it missing at https://console.developers.google.com,side?

Comment: It is very possible that you mistook the two different APIs. Google Analytics Reporting API and the Analytics API. Please check.